# Should I store token created by Firebase Admin SDK .createCustomToken(uid)?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I wonder if the token I created by Firebase Admin SDK .createCustomToken(uid) should be stored somewhere or not.

Consider the case:

---

client: new user A registeration

sever:  token = fbSDK.createCustomToken(uid)

client: use this token to auth with Firebase

---

later user A log out and log in again

should I lookup saved token for that user?

or should I again use fbSDK.createCustomToken(uid) and this token will be the same as previous or al least attached to previously created firebase user A?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While there is nothing preventing you from saving the token, there is no purpose/benefit - don't waste your time. You should check out [the docs for the Firebase Admin SDK for Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens).

The docs include the following relevant sentence when discussing the required properties of the custom tokens... specifically, the `exp` property that determines for how long the token is valid:

> The time, in seconds since the UNIX epoch, at which the token expires.
>   It can be a maximum of 3600 seconds later than the iat. Note: this
>   only controls the time when the custom token itself expires. But once
>   you sign a user in using signInWithCustomToken(), they will remain
>   signed in into the device until their session is invalidated or the
>   user signs out.

To your 2nd question, a different token is generated each time `createCustomToken()` is called. Since tokens expire, you should call the function for each successful login.

Comment: Thanks for response. So I can conclude that the next token generated with same uid will be kind of linked with previously created firebase user. Is that true?

Comment: As long as you're passing the same UID to the createCustomToken() then yes.